# How to run and test a django cloned project from github in visual studio code?

Tags: python, django, testing

I have cloned a random project and trying to run it in my local system. I am using visual studio code editor. After opening the extracted folder in editor, I have clicked on run.
At this point in time, a new chrome browser is getting opened and its showing that the server is down.

I tried setting up a virtual environment and by using the command - "python manage.py runserver" .
Even though I am unable to test that project.

Could I get some insights to get rid of this issue as early as possible please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,
check if you already install django with `pip install django`  and try to make `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Second , check for any config or env file that you need to complete to run the project.

if none of this works , share the error on your command prompt.

Comment: Django is installed successfully for that env.

Comment: But getting errors while entering python manage.py makemigrations.
File "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Django-WebApp-master\Django-WebApp-master\django_web_app\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\HP\Envs\file\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\HP\Envs\file\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()

something like this...